# Umbraco 4.7 system architecture advice to work with 200K+ nodes

Tags: c#, sql-server, umbraco

I need to create website on Umbraco 4.7 where I need to compare some products by price and some other properties (about 10). I need to make search and sorting of information, amount of products will be more than 200K+ items. I have tested now on 30K and it seems little slow. So, my question: how I should build my system?
By using umbraco nodes, than how I can increase speed of search in collection of 200K+ nodes?
Or maybe I have to combine SQl server and umbraco, in this case I will be sure that I have optimal speed to work with this amount of data?
If you have any experience or ideas how implement this solution, please give some hints. Best if you have some links for some concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with Amelvin with regards to your options. Offloading the data to a custom database implementation, using LinqToSql would be a valid option. The issue here is purely taking the strain off Umbraco.

WRT the search, I would seriously consider using Examine. It is designed to handle the amount of data you are talking about and more. It is built upon Lucene.net and so is incredibly fast regardless of the amount data.

Answer (score 2):

There are three architectural options if Umbraco is a given:

Firstly add the products and product ranges as a tree structure in the content section - but given the bloat this will cause in app_data\umbraco.config I reckon that 200,000 products will slow things down dreadfully.

Secondly use a product catalogue product like [ucommerce](http://www.ucommerce.dk/) where you can catalogue your products and then use umbraco to layout the range, product, search pages - and hook into the ucommerce API to pull the products through from your Sql Server database.  This will be more performant and there is good support but ucommerce has a fee element (for large installations - you can try it for nothing) and you won't be able to set up individual range management.

Finally you could roll your own database and product maintenance system and add your own dedicated section - but that will be costly to develop.

Personally I would use ucommerce or a similar product/catalogue maintenance Umbraco add-id as this would avoid slowing Umbraco down and give you a pre-written maintenance facility.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I wish to use ucommerce but it is not free and I need only searching and filtering info, so to pay license and use only 30% off functions won’t be good idea. I will start with Examine and then my own database if needed.

Comment: There is a free edition of ucommerce: http://www.ucommerce.dk/en/products/free-edition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Digbyswift mentioned, use Examine to perform your searches, this is much faster than the standard search and you are not hitting the database when performing a search.